# Mongo aggregation; match where a field's subfield has at least one array element greater than specified value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to find `User`s who logged in the last day.

The `userActivity` field is an object on `User`. The `userActivity` object contains a field called `hourly` which is an array of dates. I want the find any users who's hourly array contains a date greater than a day ago using aggregation.

#### User schema

```json
{
userName:"Bob",
userActivity:
    {"hourly":
       [
         "2022-05-09T02:31:12.062Z", // the user logged in
         "2022-05-09T19:37:42.870Z"  // saved as date object in the db
       ]
    }
}
```

#### query that didn't work

```js
    const oneDayAgo = new Date();
    oneDayAgo.setDate(oneDayAgo.getDate() - 1);

    const usersActiveToday = await User.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          $expr: { $gt: [oneDayAgo, '$userActivity'] },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

If today is September 13, 11pm, I'd expect the results to the above to show users who had activity between the 12th and 13th.

Instead I am getting all users returned.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use an aggregation pipeline, then one option is to use `$max` to find if there are items that are greater than `oneDayAgo`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {$expr: {$gt: [{$max: "$userActivity.hourly"}, oneDayAgo]}}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - aggregation](https://mongoplayground.net/p/syShDkrEtIW)

But, you can also do it simply by using `find`:

```
db.collection.find({
  "userActivity.hourly": {$gte: oneDayAgo}
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example - find](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PIPbo83oRhi)

Answer (score 1):

This can be considered as a 3 step process

1. Find the max value in hourly array and store it in some key(here `max`)
2. Check if the max value is greater than or equal to oneDayAgo timestamp
3. Unset the key that stored max value

Working Code Snippet:

```
const oneDayAgo = new Date();
oneDayAgo.setDate(oneDayAgo.getDate() - 1);

const usersActiveToday = await User.aggregate([
    {
        $set: {
            max: {
                $max: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$userActivity.hourly",
                        in: {
                            $max: "$$this",
                        },
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $match: {
            max: {
                $gte: oneDayAgo.toISOString(),
            },
        },
    },
    {
        $unset: "max",
    },
]);
```

Here's code in action: [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L1_ukwmlixr)

Comment: Akshit Soneji, Do you think this answer is better than the two answers that were already here?

Comment: @nimrodserok do you have any thoughts on which is better for performance?

Comment: Performance wise, use the `find` option if you can, it should be better than the aggregation pipeline. If you need an aggregation, I think my option is better than the option by @CharchitKapoor, which is better than the option by @AkshitSoneji

Answer (score 0):

You can try something along these lines:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "loggedInADayBefore": {
        "$anyElementTrue": [
          {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$userActivity.hourly",
              "as": "time",
              "in": {
                "$gte": [
                  "$$time",
                  ISODate("2022-05-13T00:00:00.000Z")
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      loggedInADayBefore: true
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      loggedInADayBefore: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Here, we `$anyElementTrue`, to find if any element in the array `hourly`, is greater than the day before, and store it as a boolean value in a new field. Then we filter the docs on the basis of that field using `$match`.

Here's the playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cqHXHaCAwhT).